# Complicated mysql join for student listing

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem with my query. The goal of the query is to display all students, whether they are in the aanweezigheid table or not.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
   s.studentNaam
   , s.studentAchterNaam
   , s.studentStamNummer
   , s.klasID
   , k.klasNaam
   , k.klasID
   , a.studentID
   , a.aanwezigTijdAan
   , a.aanwezigTijdAf
   , a.aanwezigDag
   , a.aanwezigStatus 

FROM studenten AS s 
   LEFT JOIN klassen AS k ON s.klasID=k.klasID 
   LEFT JOIN aanweezigheid AS a ON a.studentID=s.studentID
WHERE k.klasNaam = 'MD2a' 
   AND a.aanwezigDag='2012-08-28'
ORDER BY s.studentAchterNaam ASC
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a freakishly large query, no mortal genius can offer a solution without knowing the table schema, indexes set, nature of data stored in these tables, etc. Think you can provide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move your `"a"` dependency into the `ON` term. That way you won't be filtering anything out in your `WHERE`:

```
SELECT 
   s.studentNaam
   , s.studentAchterNaam
   , s.studentStamNummer
   , s.klasID
   , k.klasNaam
   , k.klasID
   , a.studentID
   , a.aanwezigTijdAan
   , a.aanwezigTijdAf
   , a.aanwezigDag
   , a.aanwezigStatus 

FROM studenten AS s 
   LEFT JOIN klassen AS k ON s.klasID=k.klasID 
   LEFT JOIN aanweezigheid AS a ON a.studentID=s.studentID
              AND a.aanwezigDag='2012-08-28'
WHERE k.klasNaam = 'MD2a' 

ORDER BY s.studentAchterNaam ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `WHERE`  conditions to `LEFT JOIN ON` clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM studenten AS s
   LEFT JOIN klassen AS k
      ON s.klasID=k.klasID
         AND k.klasNaam = 'MD2a'
   LEFT JOIN aanweezigheid AS a
      ON a.studentID=s.studentID
         AND a.aanwezigDag='2012-08-28'
ORDER BY s.studentAchterNaam ASC;
```